# If SQL Server USER_NAME() Is A sysname, Why Does It Return NVARCHAR(256)?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with a column I want to hold the value of the `USER_NAME()` function in SQL Server 2008 R2. In [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), that function is documented as having a return type of `NVARCHAR(256)`.

However, in one of the examples, they do this:

```
SELECT name FROM sysusers WHERE name = USER_NAME(1)
```

and the `sysusers.name` column has type [`sysname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which is (as I understand it) effectively an `NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL`. This inconsistency is further solidified in the documentation for [`CURRENT_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which says "This function is equivalent to `USER_NAME()`", but indicates its type is `sysname` (of course, it then goes on to have an example where it uses CURRENT_USER as a default for a `VARCHAR(30)` column...)

What gives? Is the BOL wrong about the type of `USER_NAME()`? And is it safe for me to use `NVARCHAR(128)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, let's take a look:

```
SELECT name, system_type_id, user_type_id, max_length
  FROM sys.types WHERE name IN (N'sysname', N'nvarchar');
```

Results:

```
name      system_type_id  user_type_id  max_length
--------  --------------  ------------  ----------
nvarchar  231             231           8000
sysname   231             256           256
```

`sysname` is just an alias type for `nvarchar` with a defined ***number of characters*** of 128 (not 256). The reason `sys.types` says 256 is that `nvarchar` has 2 bytes per character - so that's 128 characters x 2 bytes = 256 bytes. They do not mean the same thing by "length" that we usually do.

There is no answer to the reason "why" BOL says that - Books Online is just wrong, that's all. Proof:

```
SELECT x = USER_NAME() INTO #foo;
EXEC tempdb..sp_help '#foo';
```

Partial results:

```
Column_name  Type      Length
-----------  --------  ------
x            nvarchar  256

-----------------------^^^
---- again, this is 128 characters
```

And yes, you should be safe using `NVARCHAR(128)`, but does it cost you anything extra to match the documentation, just in case? Also stop looking at deprecated system tables like `sysusers` for guidance on data type choices and corroborating the documentation. While `sys.database_principals` and `sys.server_principals` also use `sysname` in this case, they're a much more reliable place to check how SQL Server works today, unless you really are investigating how SQL Server worked 13+ years ago.

Comment: BOL doesn't say that the length of USER_NAME() is 256; it says it has type NVARCHAR(256), which would have a length of 512.  I'm just concerned that USER_NAME() might be returning a value which isn't a sysname...

Comment: @ALEXintlsos I've clarified. I just meant something different by length. Books Online is wrong.

Comment: lol, you beat me to the Community Additions to inform them of their error!  Do you also want to let them know they shouldn't be using sysusers in their examples, so it doesn't look like they're documenting how SQL Server worked 13+ years ago?  :)  Thanks for the proof work.

Comment: @ALEXintlsos `sysname` used to be `varchar(30)` in SQL Server so maybe the code example is in fact that old!